# Any possible way to specify the name of running java virtual machine?

Tags: java, jvm, jmx

For some special purpose, I need to use `ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName` to do some special "if statement",  say if the String value returns from this method contains "Master" or "Slave".

So is it possible to specify this value when I start the java application?

Comment: This looks like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). Why do you “need to use `ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean() .getName`”, instead of using any of the gazillion alternatives, like starting with a different main class, passing a command line parameter, defining a system property, or setting an environment variable?

Answer (score 1):

On my windows system the name contains the PID and the hostname of my laptop (e.g. "14576@DESKTOP-LEOJCPM") . If you want to rely on the hostname of the operating system, that should work. But each JVM might behave differently.

See api docs:
"Returns the name representing the running Java virtual machine. The returned name string can be any arbitrary string and a Java virtual machine implementation can choose to embed platform-specific useful information in the returned name string. Each running virtual machine could have a different name."

Ref: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/management/RuntimeMXBean.html#getName--

The implementation in the Sun VM of the Method leads to a concatenation of the pid and the hostname:

```
public String getVmId() {
    int pid = getProcessId();
    String hostname = "localhost";
    try {
        hostname = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // ignore
    }
    return pid + "@" + hostname;
}
```

So it is not possible to change it directly, without modifiing the classes and therefore the behavior of the VM. The method is used in other places as well. Best advice would be to rely on a extra system property or host dependent configuration.

See: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/management/VMManagementImpl.java.html

Comment: what I want is to change this value, not inspect it's elements

Comment: In the default vm you are only able to change the hostname part by configuring your operating system.